# dialog-ready event does not fire when dialog opens in AEM 6.1?

Tags: javascript, aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

My most basic problem is to load a select field in touch UI dialog with dynamic options.
These options are coming from a external URL via webservices so please don't mention datasources here.

In classic UI is easy with optionsProvider.

In touch UI I am trying to write a script that fetches the data from the external webservice via AJAX **ON DIALOG load** and set these options in the select field.

My dialog.ready event is just not getting called.

There is another annoying issue I see with touch UI is that I can't see the edit option when I hover over a component. It shows just "delete" and "group" option. And this happens for some components only. I have to double tap to to open the dialog.
Please see image
[image]

Also see my code below to for dialog ready.

```js
(function ($, $document, $window) {
"use strict";
console.log('Namaste'); // works

$document.on("dialog-ready", function() {

    console.log('Hello'); // Does not work/fire when dialog opens

     $window.adaptTo("foundation-ui").alert("Open", "Dialog now open, event [dialog-ready]");
    if(comm) {
          var serviceUrl = xyz.config.baseUrl + '/public/movies';
          $.ajax({
                url: serviceUrl,
                cache:false,
                success: function(result){
                    console.log('Result'+JSON.stringify(result));
            }
          });
    }
    
});

$document.on("dialog-closed", function() {
    $(window).adaptTo("foundation-ui").alert("Close", "Dialog closed, event [dialog-closed]");
});

})($, $(document), $(window));
```

Comment: Why not to mention datasources? This is the recommended way of providing dynamic data for touch ui select fields. I don't know your use case, but this approauch is for me wrong and not maintainable. You cannot make sure that this will work with the next AEM version.

Comment: @d33t Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788289/load-select-options-dynamically-from-external-service-in-touch-ui-dialog-in-aem hope you understand my use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke your method on dialog open , you should set categories of your client lib as "**cq.authoring.dialog**"

It's a global category that's applies on all touch UI dialog.

Comment: You are correct. I had added cq.authoring.dialog to dependencies and I was expecting that since it is a dependency it would load before my custom js but and fire the dialog-ready event. I was wrong. Appreciate it.

Comment: Any ideas as to why the edit option is not opening when I hover over the component in touch UI ?

Comment: configuration icon is not coming for this component only ?

Comment: Yes. The configuration icon is not coming. What should I do?

Comment: Though I don't have much idea about how to set icons coming on editor toolbar, but you can verify your component's dialog structure once. 
 there is similar question on adobe forum, here is the link  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2328780